# How to move table to the left or not exceed the right margin?

Tags: tables

I am using Overleaf to take notes in my classes and I am running into trouble with a tabular column I am trying to create. My code is the following:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Crystalline Solids & Non-Crsytalline Solids \\
    \hline 
    i. Atoms and molecules are periodic in space & i. Atoms and molecules are not periodic in space \\
    \hline 
    ii. Some crystalline solids are anisotopic \\ 
    i.e the magnitudes of the physical properties like \\
    refractive index, electrical conductivity are \\
    different along difference directions \\  & ii. Physical properties are isotropic \\
    \hline 
    iii. Have sharp melting points & iii. Do not have sharp boiling points - a range is present \\
    \hline 
    iv. Breaks are observed in the cooling curve & iv. No breaks in cooling curve \\
    \hline 
    v. Breaks along sharp edges i.e breaks \\ 
    along specific "crystallographic planes" & v. Broken surfaces are irregular because there are no crystal planes \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The problem is that now my table appears like so. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUeXx.jpg
I have tried using the `\begin{table}` environment and the `\begin{figure}` environment but even after using qualifiers like `[h]` or `[ht]` the table's position in the text also changes, and the alignment is still off. How do I correct this to fit it into the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Please, always provide MWE, which reproduce your problem. Since preamble (related to your table) is unknown, we can't know how wide your table can be.
- It seems that your table is to wide that can be fit in your document text area
- For your table I would use `tabularx` and left line breaks to `X` columns and employ `makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` packages for inserting small vertical space above/below cells contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|X|}
    \hline
   & Crystalline Solids & Non-Crsytalline Solids \\
    \hline
i. & Atoms and molecules are periodic in space 
    & Atoms and molecules are not periodic in space \\
    \hline
ii. & Some crystalline solids are anisotopic 
    i.e the magnitudes of the physical properties like 
    refractive index, electrical conductivity are 
    different along difference directions   
    & Physical properties are isotropic \\
    \hline
iii. & Have sharp melting points 
    & Do not have sharp boiling points - a range is present    \\ 
    \hline
iv. & Breaks are observed in the cooling curve 
    & No breaks in cooling curve \\
    \hline
v. & Breaks along sharp edges i.e breaks 
    along specific "crystallographic planes" 
    &  Broken surfaces are irregular because there are no crystal planes \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum (1):**
An example, when for page layout is used `geometry` packages (with default settings) and for table `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec  = {c X[1,l] X[1] }
             }
   &    Crystalline Solids 
        &   Non-Crystalline Solids                  \\
i. &    Atoms and molecules are periodic in space
    & Atoms and molecules are not periodic in space \\
ii. &   Some crystalline solids are anisotropic
    i.e the magnitudes of the physical properties like
    refractive index, electrical conductivity are
    different along difference directions
        &   Physical properties are isotropic \\
iii. &  Have sharp melting points
        & Do not have sharp boiling points - a range is present    \\
iv. &   Breaks are observed in the cooling curve
        & No breaks in cooling curve \\
v. &    Breaks along sharp edges i.e breaks
    along specific "crystallographic planes"
    &  Broken surfaces are irregular because there are no crystal planes \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum (2):**

With `tabularray` package version 2021M (2021-08-01) you can simple  write your table a bit more fancy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = {1pt},
             hline{2}   = {0.6pt},
             hline{3-Y} = {solid, gray},
             vlines,
             colspec  = {c X[1,l] X[1] }
             }
% table body and tail are the same as before
```

which produce:

[image]

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for edit!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just have a question. In your first method, you use `\setcellgapes{3pt}` and `\makegapedcells`. However, even without those two lines present, the table looks fine. What exactly do these commands do?

Comment: @newtothis, add vertical space above and below of cells' contents (as already mentioned in the answer). Remove them and you will see difference: text will be very clos to horizontal lines in table. Of course at the first example. In the second example this vertical space by default 3pt, However, you can change it with option: `rowsep={<desired amount>}` . If answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept them (by clicking on the top left side of the answer).